# Jenkins and Gradle : Unable to get environment variables

Tags: jenkins, gradle

This is my gradle script,

```
String home = "${System.env.FALIB_HOME}"

task doit{
    println home
}
```

On running,

```
gradle doit
```

through command prompt Im getting,

```
D:\ThirdPartyJars
:doit UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Same command run through Jenkins is giving

```
null
:doit UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How to get value instead of null?
I'm using, 
Gradle version 2.9 
Jenkins version 2.32.2
Gradle plugin in Jenkins version 1.25

Comment: Try to print out System.getProperty("user.name") in both environments. May be your environment variables belongs to user. In addition try to print all environment variables. http://www.mytechtoday.com/2009/01/read-environment-variables-with-groovy.html

Comment: I did as you said, 
Through cmd prompt : Sandeepkumarm
Through Jenkins : COBLRDT003$.
COBLRDT003 is my host name. Thank you

Comment: You should do it on jenkins groovy script.

Comment: I printed all variables, cmd prompt result contains FALIB_HOME but Jenkins doesn't.

Comment: Yes I'm running same groovy script through cmd prompt and Jenkins.

Comment: Username is same???

Comment: Nope. I'm getting different set of variables when I printed all variables through both environments. Some variables are same, some are not, some are orphans. Gradle script is same.

Comment: Please. What is both usernames, cmd and jenkins?

Comment: cmd: sandeepkumarm     Jenkins: COBLRDT003$         I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I may be because your jenkins user actually has no home.
run this command:

`sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep jenkins` (or whatever your jenkins user is)

it's a [colon seperated list](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) but look at the last 2 `:` entries. They are: `/home/dir:/path/to/login/shell` if you have `::/bin/nologin` or something like that, there is your answer. If there is a home defined here, make sure it actually exists - if the dir doesn't exist your home will be `/`